# Xamarin Wp8.1 Silverlight - Create Appx

Tags: xamarin, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

Xamarin WinPhone produces a XAP-File to distribute the App. Can I convert this XAP File to the Appx Format? Using the MakeAppx Tool from WinPhone SDK produces the error 
 `AGHost.exe declared for element m:Application doesn't exist in the package` 
Is this a problem in Xamarin or is it generally not possible to convert a WP8.1 Silverlight project to Appx?

Comment: What would you gain by such conversion? Appx is used by WinRT application, while XAP is used by Silverlight applications.

Comment: It is a customer request :)

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it is possible. And as I wrote earlier, you don't gain anything from it.

Comment: I know it doesn't really make sense, but you know, customer is king :)

Comment: Well, you will have one unhappy customer then.